# Polymer : How to procedurally add nodes to a polymer-element's Light Dom, from inside the element?

Tags: polymer

I am trying to define a custom polymer-element (`groups-manager`), which takes a JSON configuration, and produces its contents (a set of custom polymer-elements called `generic-group`):

```
<polymer-element name="groups-manager" attributes="display type config">
    <template>      

        <content id="content" select="generic-group">

            <template repeat="{{c in config}}">
                <generic-group id="{{c.groupName}}" config="{{c}}" type="{{type}}">
                </generic-group>
            </template>

       </content>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer('groups-manager',{})
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Although contained in a `<content>` node, my `<generic-group>` nodes become parts of the Shadow DOM.

Is there a way to have the `<generic-group>` nodes that are produced by the template, exposed in the light DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add them with `Polymer.dom(this).appendChild()`.
The nodes you add will be put in the light dom, and the `<content>` tag will display them into the element.